# Django admin Tabular Inline 'Add More' not showing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using `Tabular Inline` in my site admin. It was working as expected, but since my upgrade from Django 1.9 to Django 1.10, it is not showing up in the screen. However, when I click on the add foreign key and the pop up appears, the add more button is showing up. Please see the screenshots.

I have tried downgrading back to Django 1.9 and 1.8, but it is still same. I have also done `collectstatic` with `clear`, still same results. Please help.

In my admin.py

```
class OfferAreaInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OfferArea
    extra = 1

class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [OfferAreaInline]
    ...
```

[In the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H5Em.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H5Em.png): [image]

[On the pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXnqp.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXnqp.png): [image]

Comment: Are you working with virtualenv?

Comment: @trantu I have two setups. One has virtualenv and other doesn't. This issue is same on both.

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, it was because the static files were not loaded properly. Check your static files path.

Comment: I'm having this issue with Django 2.1, "Add another" button is missing. I've run 'collectstatic' and no help.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example for inline with 'Add More':

```
class ReviewInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ('author','text','rating')
    model = Review
    extra = 3
    max_num = 5
```

Noitce the "extra" var. for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Comment: both `extra` and `max_num` are important here. The link won't show up if the currently displayed forms exceeds `max_num`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the button appears based on a JS file, in my case the error came from not running collectstatic since a django upgrade, so check the browser console and check for any errors.